# Python: TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

Tags: python

I am getting an error from this Python code:

```
with open('names') as f:
    names = f.read()
    names = names.split('\n')
    names.pop(len(names) - 1)
    names = shuffle(names)
    f.close()

assert len(names) > 100
```

Error:

```
Python: TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

The assert statement is throwing this error, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: two minor things: as Levon said, `names = list` doesn't assign an empty list to names, that would be `names = []`. also you can do `del names[-1]` instead of `names.pop(len(names) - 1)`

Comment: use `names.strip().split('\n')`  then there's no need of `pop()`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`shuffle(names)` is an in-place operation. Drop the assignment.

This function returns `None` and that's why you have the error:

```
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to assign `names` to `list` or `[]` or anything else until you wish to use it.

It's neater to use a list comprehension to make the list of names.

`shuffle` modifies the list you pass to it. It always returns `None`

If you are using a context manager (`with ...`) you don't need to close the file explicitly

```
from random import shuffle

with open('names') as f:
    names = [name.rstrip() for name in f if not name.isspace()]
    shuffle(names)

assert len(names) > 100
```

Answer (score 3):

What is the purpose of this

```
 names = list;
```

? Also, no `;` required in Python.

Do you want

```
 names = []
```

or

```
 names = list()
```

at the start of your program instead? Though given your particular code, there's no need for this statement to create this `names` variable since you do so later when you read data into it from your file.

@JBernardo has already pointed out the other (and more major) problem with the code.

Comment: ok but what's the difference between an empty array and declaring names as a list type in python?

Comment: @JBernardo That's true, you are right of course since he reads value from a file into that variable, but it's still a problem (perhaps not *the* problem)

Comment: @mavix, `names = list` means names is now a `<type 'list'>` object, not `[]`.

Comment: @mavix You are assigning names to the class `list` and not an instance of that class. You could do `names = list()` but `names = []` is better

Comment: what's the difference between the two?

Comment: @mavix `names = list()` would be an alternative, notice the `()`. Here is a short [intro on lists](http://effbot.org/zone/python-list.htm) with more information.

Comment: am I correct in interpreting that the two are the same, but that names = [] is the standard aesthetically? PS how do I highlight things as code inline like you guys are doing?

Comment: @mavix It's mostly a matter of style/preferences - I recall reading that there might be some subtle differences perhaps, but I don't remember. I usually just use the `=[]`. To highlight code use backticks. This [link to a reference](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) will give you much more details on how to use the editor features. @jamylak just said it (`list()` vs `[]`)!

Comment: @mavix `[]` looks better/more pythonic, also it will be created faster since it is optimized by the interpreter while `list` involves the function lookup and function call.

Answer (score 0):

I was faces this issue but after change object into str, problem solved.
str(fname).isalpha():